# Question about Homomorphisms and Codomain

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I was working on a homomorphism problem and had a quick question:

I am working with the group $G: \{-50, -49, \cdots, 47, 48, 49\}.$ The binary operator is, for $x, y \in G$, $x+y = (x+y) \pmod {100}.$

I thought of the following homorphism, $\phi: G \rightarrow G$:

$\phi(x) = 
\begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } x = 0 \\
1 &\mbox{if } x \ne 0 
\end{cases}$

I know one of the criteria for a homomorphism is that we must have $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$. I was thinking that if we let $x = -50$ and $y = -1$, we get $\phi(50) = \phi(-50)\phi(-1)$. However, $50$ is not an element of $G$. Does this mean that the homomorphism is invalid or can I say that since $50 = -50 \pmod {100}$, $\phi(50)$ is just $\phi(-50)$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  $\phi$ is not a homomorphism because $\phi(1+1)=\phi(2)=1\ne \phi(1)+\phi(1)=1+1=2$

Comment: but must a homomorphism satisfy $\phi(x+y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$? In the reading that I did, that wasn't listed as a condition.

Comment: If the group operation is written multiplicatively, $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$; if it is written additively, $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$

Comment: So let's say I changed the binary operators to $x*y = xy \pmod{100}.$ Then, would the above homomorphism be valid?

Comment: That's not a group.  $1$ would be the identity element, and $2$ has no inverse

Comment: is there a way to have the elements of $G$ be the ones described above that also has homomorphism $\phi$ as described above?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917711/quick-question-about-finite-group-homomorphisms)